# Location Service on Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-10.0, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am trying to get lat long after some intervals using FusedLocationProviderClient. I have created a service which runs in background. But the issue is that when my device is locked (Screen is off) the device sends about 3-5 lat long and then stops in Android 10 (was working fine in Android 9 and Previous versions). Did Android 10 had some changes/Updates which is stopping me from getting location updates. Any help will be grateful

Menifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".LocationService">
</service>
```

LocationService.java

```
public void requestLocationUpdates() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL); // two minute interval
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }
}

LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {


        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {

            Log.e("mLocationCallbackLat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            Log.e("mLocationCallbackLong", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

        }
```

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: The issue was with the permission. I followed the following guide and it is now working fine.  https://www.journaldev.com/28028/android-10-location-permissions